# C - String Reversal Function with Pointers Not Running

Tags: arrays, c, string

I understand that issues with string-reversal in C are numerous on this site, but I seem to be having a uniquely odd problem: the reversal logic simply does not run despite seeming to be set up correctly.
I wanted to write a program to reverse a given string in-place, by moving two pointers from the front and back of the string together:

```
void reverse_inplace_pointer(char *string_in, int length) {
    char *back_ptr = string_in + (length - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        char swap_char = *back_ptr;

        /* Dereference pointers to double-check values */
        printf("\nCurrent front char: %c\nCurrent back char: %c", *string_in, *back_ptr);
        
        /* Swap */
        *back_ptr  = *string_in;
        *string_in = swap_char;
        printf("\nSwap %u successful.", i + 1);
    
        string_in++;
        back_ptr--;
    } 
}
```

Calling this with a test string:
`char *test_string = "TestMeTestMe";`
nets the result:

```
Current front char: T
Current back char: e
```

And then execution just stops, at the assignment of the character pointed to by `*string_in` to the location pointed to by `*back_ptr`. If I remove the assignment, the program will quite happily move the pointers along the test string and print out each character without issue.

I looked for other examples of reassigning elements in arrays and found the logic in tutorials to be almost identical to mine. I copied this example wholesale as a test:

```
void steal_this_function(char *string) {
    printf("\nEntering function:");
    int length, c;
    char *begin, *end, temp;

    length = strlen(string);

    begin = string;
    end = string;

    for (c = 0; c < (length - 1); c++) {
        end++;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < length / 2; c++) {
        temp = *end;
        *end = *begin;
        *begin = temp;

        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

The result is the same - it stops on the first iteration and the program exits. The only difference here is the reuse of the original pointer `string`, which is then walked to the end of the string with a `for`-loop.

Clearly I have some confusion here with pointers, but my understanding was that `*back_ptr = *string_in;` effectively says *dereference the pointer `string_in`, then go to the location pointed to by `back_ptr` and store whatever it contains there.*

I'm also compiling with the `-Wall` flag on GCC and it isn't finding any issues. This is frustrating because it should be very simple.

Comment: @user3121023 That should be the answer and not a comment :)

Comment: @user3121023 Ah, I can't believe that was it. 

It was a trivial issue, but if you want to copy your comment into an answer then I'll accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function requires modifiable char array. It cannot be called when parameter is a pointer to thestring literal.

Some additional remarks.

1. This kind of function should return the reversed string. It is possible to use it as a parameter of another functions.
2. strlen returns `size_t` not `int`. Use the correct type in the loops as well

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end = str + strlen(str) - !!*str;
    char *wrk = str;

    while(end > wrk)
    {
        char tmp = *wrk;
        *wrk++ = *end;
        *end-- = tmp;
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void)

{
    char str[] = "0123456789";

    printf("%s\n", reverse(str));
}
```

Comment: `char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;` produces an invalid pointer when `str` is an empty string. Comparing `str` and `end` has undefined behavior in this case an would indeed malfunction on some architectures such as 80286's large model with segmented pointers. You should use `char *end = str + strlen(str);`, `while (str + 1 < end)` and `*wrk++ = *--end;`.

Comment: @chqrlie disagree. Both pointers reference the same array. The comparison is defined per C standard.

Comment: I wrote the comment before you made the change. `char *end = str + strlen(str) - !!*str;` is a hideous hack with very poor pedagogical value (except for code golfing). Your suggesting the correct type `size_t` shows you care about teaching the right thing, so you could move the whole loop with initialization inside an `if (*str) { ... }`.

Comment: @chqrlie all string functions in the standard libraries do not check for NULL pointer and I am consistent with it

Comment: This has nothing to do with null pointers, but rather the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

> Calling this with a test string: `char *test_string = "TestMeTestMe";`

That's the culprit, as noted in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328529/c-string-reversal-function-with-pointers-not-running#comment111982215_63328529), it declares a pointer to the memory where the string literal `"TestMeTestMe"` is stored, which you are not allowed to modify.

You should declare an array instead.

```
char test_string[] = "TestMeTestMe"; // Now test_string is a modifiable
                                     // NULL-terminated char[13]
```

> I'm also compiling with the -Wall flag on GCC and it isn't finding any issues.

`-Wall` it's not enough, but you can use `-Wwrite-strings` to catch this particular issue (see e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Wv8ech)).